# Can't extract timezone_hour from postgres timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

`ERROR:  timestamp units "timezone" not supported`

That's the error I get for all timezone fields.

Here's a minimal query you can run:

```
select extract(timezone_hour from now()::timestamptz at time zone 'US/Eastern');
```

What I want is the utc offset in hours. So this should return -4.

The requirement is that I use a dynamic time zone in the query. So I have a table of "facilities" with time zone strings, and I need to get the current time for each one.

So my end query should look something like this:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(timezone_hour from now() with time zone timezone)  # timezone is the name of the field
FROM facilities;
```

I thought I had it for a second with this, but this is giving me my current offset, not the offset of the tz I'm passing:

```
select 
    extract(timezone_hour from (select now()::timestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern'))

 date_part 
-----------
        -7
```

I ended up getting this to work with creating two timestamps, one at utc and one at the desired time zone, but I'll leave this open just in case there's a better solution than my current one:

```
select 
    extract(hour from (
                   select (
                       select now() at time zone 'US/Eastern') - (select now() at time zone 'UTC')));

 date_part 
-----------
        -4
```

Comment: I think your solution is good.

Comment: Thanks, @LaurenzAlbe I'll stick with this, then. It seems like I should just be able to use extract on a single time stamp, but this isn't adding a lot of work to the aggregation, so I'm not too worried.